# Почему событие NULL, если подписка была

Tags: c#, unity3d

Событие:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public List<Item> ItemList;
    public event EventHandler OnItemListChanged;

    public void CheckEvent()
    {
        if (OnItemListChanged == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Event is null!");
        }
        else if (OnItemListChanged != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Event is not null!");
        }
    }

    public void AddItem(Item item)
    {
        ItemList.Add(item);

        CheckEvent();

        OnItemListChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Подписка:

```
public class UI_Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Inventory _inventory;

    public void SetInventory(Inventory inventory) // вызывается при создании инвентаря
    {
        _inventory = inventory;

        _inventory.OnItemListChanged += Inventory_OnItemListChanged;

        _inventory.CheckEvent();

        RefreshInventoryItems();
    }

    private void Inventory_OnItemListChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshInventoryItems();
    }

    public void RefreshInventoryItems()
    {
    }
```

Во время подписки событие не пустое, но во время вызова оно пустое.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как работают классы Unity.
Но как вариант создай конструктор класса Inventory и инициализируй в нем все нужные переменные:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public event EventHandler OnItemListChanged;
    public List<Item> ItemList;

    public Inventory()
    {
      this.ItemList = new List<Item>();
      this.OnItemListChanged = new EventHandler((sender, args) => { /* event logic */ });
    }
    
    // do other stuff
}
```

Comment: У меня и так происходит инициализация в конструкторе, но я не понимаю, что вы делаете здесь: OnItemListChanged = new EventHandler((sender, args). Разве событие надо инициализировать?

Comment: в юнити инициализация обьекта обычно происходит в методе Start(). А лист не имеет смысла инициализировать в статре - можно создать инстанс изначально там где обьявляется глобальная переменная. Все остальное правильно)

Comment: Все решил проблему. Оказывается я в другом классе случайно создавал новый объект Inventory)